# JavaScript Event Trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Below is a series of events that should run as listed, but I used a timer to delay the events, which is not a good practice, is there a way to run them after each other without the delay timer?

```
$(".component-select",closestTable).val(parseData.component).trigger("change");

setTimeout(function() {
    $(".key-select",closestTable).val(parseData.key).trigger("change");
},1000);  

setTimeout(function() {                                                 
    $.each(parseData.instance, function (dIndex, dValue){                             
        $(".add_instance",closestTable).trigger("click");
        $("tbody select:last",closestTable).val(dValue).trigger("change");
    });
},1500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use [jQuery deferred promises](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

another potentially useful resource:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises/